# JSR223 Sampler return Response same as Request for EDIFACT message in JMeter

Tags: performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

JSR223 Sampler return Response same as Request for EDIFACT message.
Request:

```
def payload = "UNB+IATA:1+1S+XX+121103+FF168019110033++ETK1+O'\n" +
"UNH+1+TKCREQ:00:1:IA'\n" +
"MSG+:131'\n" +
"ORG+1S+99999999:X7HH+VZX++T+GR+CXN'\n" +
"TKT+676713121:T'\n" +
"UNT+5+1'\n" +
"UNZ+1+FF168019110033
```

Response:

```
"UNB+IATA:1+1S+XX+121103+FF168019110033++ETK1+O'\n" +
"UNH+1+TKCREQ:00:1:IA'\n" +
"MSG+:131'\n" +
"ORG+1S+99999999:X7HH+VZX++T+GR+CXN'\n" +
"TKT+676713121:T'\n" +
"UNT+5+1'\n" +
"UNZ+1+FF168019110033
```

Log:

```
2023-02-07 15:33:39,890 DEBUG o.a.j.p.t.s.TCPSampler: Created org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler@4a6c4b41
2023-02-07 15:33:39,912 DEBUG o.a.j.p.t.s.TCPSampler: Created org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.TCPSampler@7bd45f7b
2023-02-07 15:33:39,939 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2023-02-07 15:33:39,939 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2023-02-07 15:33:39,942 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2023-02-07 15:33:40,147 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2023-02-07 15:33:40,147 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2023-02-07 15:33:40,147 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will start next loop on error
2023-02-07 15:33:40,147 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 perThread=1000.0 delayedStart=false
2023-02-07 15:33:40,150 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2023-02-07 15:33:40,150 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2023-02-07 15:33:40,150 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2023-02-07 15:33:40,162 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1
2023-02-07 15:33:40,162 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2023-02-07 15:33:40,162 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2023-02-07 15:33:40,162 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)

SampleResult fields:
ContentType:
DataEncoding: windows-1252
```

Steps followed:

1. Set up  TCP  in JMeter properties:

- tcp.handler=TCPClientImpl
- eolByte = 111
- tcp.eolByte=1000
- tcp.charset=
- tcp.status.prefix=Status=
- tcp.status.suffix=.
- tcp.binarylength.prefix.length=2

2. TCP Sampler Config

- TCPClient classname=TCPClientImpl
- Servername=xxxxxx
- Port: 3432
- Timeouts:  Connect(2000ms,)Response: 2000ms
- Reuse Connection -enabled

3. JSR223 Sampler
   Payload Request :

```
def payload = "UNB+IATA:1+1S+XX+121103+FF168019110033++ETK1+O'\n" +
"UNH+1+TKCREQ:00:1:IA'\n" +
"MSG+:131'\n" +
"ORG+1S+99999999:X7HH+VZX++T+GR+CXN'\n" +
"TKT+676713121:T'\n" +
"UNT+5+1'\n" +
"UNZ+1+FF168019110033'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this code:

```
def payload = "UNB+IATA:1+1S+XX+121103+FF168019110033++ETK1+O'\n" +
"UNH+1+TKCREQ:00:1:IA'\n" +
"MSG+:131'\n" +
"ORG+1S+99999999:X7HH+VZX++T+GR+CXN'\n" +
"TKT+676713121:T'\n" +
"UNT+5+1'\n" +
"UNZ+1+FF168019110033"
```

is the complete code for the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) - it does absolutely nothing.

If you want to send it over TCP you need to put the payload into "Text to send" field of the TCP Sampler:

[image]

If you want to send the "payload" using JSR223 Sampler you need to add the relevant code to do it, the simplest one is:

```
def payload = "UNB+IATA:1+1S+XX+121103+FF168019110033++ETK1+O'\n" +
        "UNH+1+TKCREQ:00:1:IA'\n" +
        "MSG+:131'\n" +
        "ORG+1S+99999999:X7HH+VZX++T+GR+CXN'\n" +
        "TKT+676713121:T'\n" +
        "UNT+5+1'\n" +
        "UNZ+1+FF168019110033"

def socket = new Socket('xxxxxx', 3432)

socket.withStreams { input, output ->
    log.info(input.newReader().readLine())
    output << payload
}
```

The output will go to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)